# r syntax: purpose of `[1]`

Tags: r, syntax

I found this code on :http://onertipaday.blogspot.co.il/search/label/descriptive%20statistic
The code is describing a workaround for finding the `min` and `max` in a dataset that has `inf` and `-inf` in a vector. However I don't understand the purpose of the `[1]` and `[2]` in the last two lines of code.

```
data <- c(-Inf, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, Inf)
max(data)
# Return Inf
min(data)
# Return -Inf
# To solve the problem I went to:
range(data, finite=TRUE)
# Then you can do
myMinimum <- range(data, finite=TRUE)[1]
myMaximum <- range(data, finite=TRUE)[2]
```

Comment: well, range returns a vector of length 2

Comment: By using `[1]` or `[2]` on a vector, you can extract the first or second element of that vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range function returns a vector of length 2, with the first being the minimum and the second being the maximum.

For instance:

```
> a <- 15:30
> range(a)
[1] 15 30
```

Using the `[]` operator you extract the desired element

```
 > range(a)[1]
 [1] 15
 > range(a)[2]
 [1] 30
```

Or you can also do:

```
 r <- range(a)
 my.min <- r[1]
 my.max <- r[2]
```

For more information read `?range`.

Also, you can directly use the `min` and `max` functions.